# Get rid of the strip line under the TabWidget

Tags: android

I'm using Android 3.0.

I've created `TabHost` with `TabWidget` in my layout and I add the tabs during runtime.
I want to get rid of the blue line under the `TabWidget` which also indicates on the active tab. I've tried to set the strip to disabled but it didn't help.
How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,
I found a solution for this issue.
When creating the TabSpec, I've set an indicator which is an inflated layout resource.
After using this, the strip is not shown anymore on the tabs' header.

```
// Inflates the icon layout for the tab
LinearLayout tabIconLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, null);

TabSpec tabSpec = tabsHost.newTabSpec("...")
        .setIndicator(tabIconLayout)
        .setContent(mContentFactory);

mSocialNetworkTabsHost.addTab(tabSpec);
```

Thanks anyway for your help

Answer (score 1):

If all of above way don't work, please try:

```
 tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackground(null);
 tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackground(null);
 ...
```

It work for me.

Answer (score 0):

this should normally do it.
how did you disable the strip?

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().setStripEnabled(false);
```

Comment: I've tried two ways: One as you wrote and the second by the xml layout 'android:tabStripEnabled="false"' (this is in TabWidget)

Answer (score 0):

Or do `android:tabStripEnabled="false"` in your XML

Comment: What about disabling the strip from left and right side? Are you using some custome drawables for your tabs?

Comment: have u got the result?it is not solving my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
  tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackground(null);
  tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackground(null);
  ...
```

I fixed it by this way.